# django models DateTimeField(default=next 3-days)

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
      event = models.DateTimeField(default=next 3-days)
```

How to get default next 3 days?
Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "next 3 days"? That's a *period*, not a *datetime*.

Comment: yes period, next 3 period

Comment: Do you mean IN 3 days, starting today?

Comment: But it is default *value*, not the *range*. You can not say "our meeting is at next 3-days"...

Comment: no i can say 'Our meeting after 3 days'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a callable that returns the datetime that you want, for example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

def in_three_days():
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(days=3)

class TestModel(models.Model):
      event = models.DateTimeField(default=in_three_days)
```

If you use `x = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)` as in Vaibhav's answer, then `x` will be calculated when the module is loaded, not when each new `TestModel` instance is created.

Comment: the idea is correct but, in the function "in_three_days" you use datetime.now() which is timezone unaware and may cause problems

Comment: @GiorgiJambazishvili good point, I've updated the code to use `timezone.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

```
import datetime
class TestModel(models.Model):
      x = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
      event = models.DateTimeField(default = x)
```

Comment: This will calculate `x` once when the server loads. You should use a callable that returns the datetime.

Comment: i didn't get it.. you mean to say that defining a short function which return `x` will be better?? how?? can you please explain a little bit please

Answer (score 0):

As some answers noted you have to use callable, but also you should include timezone aware datetime object to properly set next 3 days, which will work as expected and won't give you timezone unaware datetime objects, which relies on server time

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz

def next_day_dt(n=3):
    return tz.localtime(tz.now()) + tz.timedelta(days=n)

class TestModel(models.Model):
    event = models.DateTimeField(default=next_day_dt)
...
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the best solution so far:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyModel(models.Model):
   mydate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=3))
```